# Type lambdas break implicit resolution

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation, kind-projector

Could someone please explain this behavior and provide a workaround?
Scala 2.12.7, kind-projector 0.9.8, scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"

```
package tictactoe

import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
import tictactoe.ListOps.HasF

sealed trait LowPrio {
  implicit def ifTail[F[_], H, X <: HList](implicit ev: HasF[F, X]): HasF[F, H :: X] = null
}

object ListOps extends LowPrio {

  //Checks that property F[A] holds for at least one element of X
  sealed trait HasF[F[_], X <: HList]

  implicit def ifhead[F[_], H, X <: HList](implicit ev: F[H]): HasF[F, H :: X] = null
}

object Runner {
  type IsString[A] = =:=[A, String]

  //Works
  implicitly[HasF[IsString, String :: Int :: HNil]]

  /*
  Doesn't work
  could not find implicit value for parameter e: tictactoe.ListOps.HasF[[A]A =:= String,String :: Int :: shapeless.HNil]
  implicitly[HasF[Lambda[A => =:=[A, String]], String :: Int :: HNil]]
   */
  implicitly[HasF[Lambda[A => =:=[A, String]], String :: Int :: HNil]]

  /*
  Doesn't work
  could not find implicit value for parameter e: tictactoe.ListOps.HasF[[α$0$]α$0$ =:= String,String :: Int :: shapeless.HNil]
  implicitly[HasF[=:=[?, String], String :: Int :: HNil]]
   */
  implicitly[HasF[=:=[?, String], String :: Int :: HNil]]
}
```

Comment: Why isn't using `IsString` a workaround?

Comment: @DmytroMitin actually I wanted to do partial application of `F`:  `type Has[X <: HList, T] = HasF[({type E[a] = =:=[T, a]})#E, X]`

Comment: Ok, you can do this introducing  a type like `IsString`: `type E[a] = =:=[T, a]` `type Has[X <: HList, T] = HasF[E, X]`.

Comment: It doesn't compile.`T` is used before declared.

Comment: What if you try `trait Has[X <: HList, T] { type E[a] = =:=[T, a]; type Out = HasF[E, X] }`?

Comment: Implicit resolution doesn't work well with existentials and type projections `A#B` are not existentials precisely but like them `a.B forSome { val a: A }`. So the type lambda `({ type E[a] = =:=[T, a] })#E` is like (actually a supertype of) `x.E forSome { val x: { type E[a] = =:=[T, a] }}` (a combination of existential and structural types). See also https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/23/type-projection.html

Comment: @DmytroMitin thanks. Can't say that I totally get it but "doesn't work for a reason" is precise enough for me now.